# VPN only in a single Google Chrome tab

Tags: google-chrome, vpn, google-chrome-extensions, browser-tabs

I'm wondering if there is the possibility to use VPN only for a specific tab in Google Chrome.
Now I'm using a Google Chrome VPN extension, but it has a systemic effect.

Comment: This is not possible.

Comment: Hello @harrymc maybe by running an appropriate script in a single tab it's possible to route the traffic through a VPN?

Comment: A VPN entails changes on the operating system level. A browser doesn't have the permissions for that, and it certainly will not work for only one tab.

Comment: @harrymc if I use a VPN extension in Chrome the only IP that changes is the one visible in Chrome; in fact if I try to check my IP in Firefox while the VPN extension is on the result is the right IP.

Comment: This sounds more like a proxy than VPN.

Comment: @harrymc the extension is VeePN; yes it's a proxy, I read the description.

Comment: A browser can use a proxy and this isn't on the OS level. However, this will affect all the tabs. You'll need to use two browsers, probably not the same, such as Chrome and one of Edge or Firefox..

Comment: thank you for the suggestion @harrymc

Answer (score 1):

Add another user to Chrome and use a VPN extension for this user. It will be in different Chrome windows (not just in another tab), but it is a solution nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest multi account containers pointing at a Docker container running Nickguitar/VPNTabs but that is only possible on Firefox.

With that you can default specific domains to automatically open in the container that uses the VPN.